# I want to access remote Postgres database from home. What IP should I allow in pg_hba.conf?

Tags: postgresql

I am behind a router. Can I allow "192.168.0.111" or does it have to be my external IP address? I am reading up these posts.

http://sabarish4u.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/remote-pgsql-database-access/

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Should I be stressed about security issues this way? My server is up to date with no unnecessary stuff running and I have strong password.  This set up will really help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tunnel the access over SSH and just allow localhost access.  Access over a tunnel is usually more secure.

If you want to allow access without tunneling you will need to use your external address.  Be aware that your home external address may change.  Depending on your ISP's configuration this may occur relatively frequently.

Postgress may allow TLS encrypted connections.  This should be used if you are not tunnelling your connections.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. With the limited understand of what I am doing, I dont think I can tunnel/SSH. I think I would have to let it accept my IP address. Thanks again for the help.